# Save Jenkins pipeline stage details (time, pass, fail)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a fairly new Jenkins user but I started out with Job DSL and then switched to pipeline after the Jenkins World 2017 conference.

The tests are large amount of data so the stages can take as little 4min but last long as 5hrs+. I'm SQA so my goal is to automate some of my functional testing and track the results.

my pipeline example:
git code-> git test data -> build -> test01 -> test02 -> test03

**Is there a way to export/save time to complete each stage?**

and

**Is there a way export/save pass/fail rate of individual stages?**